# Pushing events between bridged (aggregated) classes C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class hierarchy like bellow:

```cs
class A 
{
    event evA<ArgA>
        
    Run(){
        evA.Invoke()
    }
}

class B
{
    event evB<ArgB>
        
    Run(){
        evB.Invoke()
    }
}

class C
{

    even A<ArgA> //?
    event B<ArgB> //?
    event C<ArgC>
    
    A a;
    B b;
    C(A a, B b)
    {
    
    }
    
    void Run()
    {
        a.Run();
        b.Run();
         
    }
}

class D
{
    event evD<ArgD>
    
    C c;
    D(C c)
    {
        ///in this class I want to ract on event A,B,C
    }
    
    Run()
}
```

Class A has its own event same as the class B and both has different args. Class C uses class A and B as dependency.

Then class C is used in class D as an dependency and runs its methods with causes that all classes A,B,C,D raising their own events.

What is the best approach to get all this events (evA,evB,evC) in class D:

​   Should I declare event A and B in class C and forward this events or there is some better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not subscribe to the events on class D? c.a.evA += HandleA this way you d not need to declare extra events on class C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work, with no need for extra events

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        var c = new C(a, b);
        var d = new D(c);

        d.Run();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
class A
{
    internal event EventHandler<ArgA> eventA;

    internal void Run()
    {
        eventA?.Invoke(this, new ArgA());
    }
}

class B
{
    internal event EventHandler<ArgB> eventB;

    internal void Run()
    {
        eventB?.Invoke(this, new ArgB());
    }
}

class C
{

    internal event EventHandler<ArgC> eventC;

    internal A A { get; set; }
    internal B B { get; set; }

    internal C(A a, B b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    internal void Run()
    {
        A.Run();
        B.Run();
    }

}

class D
{
    internal event EventHandler<ArgD> eventD;

    internal C C { get; set; }
    internal D(C c)
    {
        C = c;
    }

    internal void Run()
    {
        C.A.eventA += A_eventA;
        C.B.eventB += B_eventB;
        C.Run();
    }

    private void B_eventB(object sender, ArgB e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B was triggered");
    }

    private void A_eventA(object sender, ArgA e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A was triggered");
    }
}
```